# How to prevent truncating of string in unit test python

Tags: python, string, unit-testing, testing, truncated

I am doing a unit test in Python for my program and I would like to do an `assertEquals` test.

My code looks something like this:

```
class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_parser(self):
          self.assertEquals(parser,"some long string", "String is not equal")
```

However, as my string is too long, I got something like `testing[471 chars]0 != testing[473 chars]`. I wanna see what is the exact difference between both the strings instead of seeing the truncated ones.

Anyone has an idea how to counter this problem?

Comment: You mean that the `assertEquals` output doesn't show you the full output?

Comment: yeah it does not show me the full output. Instead i see something like [471 chars] and [473 chars] respectively.

Comment: Have you tried setting `self.maxDiff` to a higher value or to `None`? The assertion message does tell you this.

Comment: I tried setting the maxDiff to None but I still receive the same output.

Comment: Where did you set that? In the test function itself? On the testcase as a class attribute?

Answer (score 24):

To replace `[... chars]` and `[truncated]...` with actual characters (no matter how long, and no matter what the type of the compared values are), add this to your `*_test.py` file:

```py
if 'unittest.util' in __import__('sys').modules:
    # Show full diff in self.assertEqual.
    __import__('sys').modules['unittest.util']._MAX_LENGTH = 999999999
```

Indeed, as other answers have noted, setting `self.maxDiff = None` doesn't help, it doesn't make the `[... chars]` disappear. However, this setting helps showing other types of long diffs, so my recommendation is doing both.

Comment: thank you for this, all the other answers point to `maxDiff = None` which didn't help.

Answer (score 21):

So, I landed on this question because I had an issue where I was using `assertEqual()` and `self.maxDiff = None` wouldn't cause the full output to be displayed. Tracing through, it turned out that because the types of the two objects were different (one was a list, one was a generator), the code path that would make use of `self.maxDiff` wasn't used. So, if you run into the issue where you need the full diff and `self.maxDiff` isn't working, ensure the types of your two compared objects are the same.

Comment: To make this even more pernicious, the diff rendering might make it look like they are the same type, when they are not. When testing serializers you get and `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`, so comparing these two `self.maxDiff` has no effect. You have to do `self.assertEqual(dict(result),expected_result))`

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the original question: how to get the full dump of two strings (without shortening) if they are different.

Comment: self.maxDiff = None didn't work for me even with casting both objects to str.  pts's answer did work.

Answer (score 12):

`unittest.TestCase.assertEquals` tries to give you the actual difference in the string while at the same time making the text *fit in your screen*.

To do this it truncates the common sections, so sections that have *no differences* are truncated by replacing them with `[<count> chars]` chunks:

```
>>> case.assertEqual('foo' * 200, 'foo' * 100 + 'bar' + 'foo' * 99)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 821, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1194, in assertMultiLineEqual
    self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 666, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 'foof[291 chars]oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo[255 chars]ofoo' != 'foof[291 chars]oofoobarfoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo[255 chars]ofoo'
Diff is 1819 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.
```

In the above example, the two strings share a long prefix, which has been shortened by replacing 291 characters with `[291 chars]` in both prefixes. They also share a long postfix, again shortened in both locations by replacing text with `[255 chars]`.

The *actual* difference is still being displayed, right in the middle.

Of course, when you make that difference too long, then even the difference is truncated:

```
>>> case.assertEqual('foo' * 200, 'foo' * 80 + 'bar' * 30 + 'foo' * 80)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 821, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1194, in assertMultiLineEqual
    self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 666, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 'foof[231 chars]oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo[315 chars]ofoo' != 'foof[231 chars]oofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarba[285 chars]ofoo'
Diff is 1873 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.
```

Here, the common postfix is starting to differ, but the start of the difference is still visible, and should help you figure out where the text went wrong.

If this is still not enough, you can either increase or eliminate the diff limits. Set the [`TestCase.maxDiff` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.maxDiff) to a higher number (the default is 8 * 80, 80 lines of text), or set it to `None` to eliminate altogether:

```
self.maxDiff = None
```

Note that unless your string contains *newlines* that the diff is likely to be unreadable:

> AssertionError: 'foof[231
>   chars]oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo[315 chars]ofoo'
>   != 'foof[231 chars]oofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarba[285
>   chars]ofoo'
>   - foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
>   ?
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   + foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarfoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
>   ?
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

In that case it may be more useful to *wrap* your input and output texts:

```
from textwrap import wrap

self.maxDiff = None
self.assertEquals(wrap(parser), wrap("some long string"), "String is not equal")
```

just so you get better and more readable diff output:

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> case.assertEqual(wrap('foo' * 200), wrap('foo' * 80 + 'bar' * 30 + 'foo' * 80))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 821, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1019, in assertListEqual
    self.assertSequenceEqual(list1, list2, msg, seq_type=list)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1001, in assertSequenceEqual
    self.fail(msg)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 666, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['foo[244 chars]oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoof'[336 chars]foo'] != ['foo[244 chars]oofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarb'[306 chars]foo']

First differing element 3:
'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoof'
'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarb'

  ['foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoof',
   'oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo',
   'ofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo',
-  'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoof',
-  'oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo',
+  'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarb',
+  'arbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarfoofoofoofoofoofoofo',
   'ofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo',
   'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoof',
   'oofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo',
-  'ofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo']
+  'ofoofoofoo']
```

Comment: The proposed solution (`wrap(...)`) works only for strings; it raises an exception if self.assertEqual is called on non-string types (whose repr is long). See my answer for a solution which works on all types.